# Write to same location in a console window with java

Tags: java, console, io

I would like to write a character to the same location in a console window.

The characters I would like to write are `/` `-` `\` `_`. This will get me a little spinner I can display to show progress or loading.

How can you write the chars to the same location though? Otherwise, you will wind up with something like this `/-\_/-\_/-\`

Comment: Is this for a windows terminal or some other terminal?

Comment: Windows right now, but would like it to be cross platform

Answer (score 23, accepted):

With Java 6 you can use the [`Console`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) to do something like this:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        String[] spinner = new String[] {"\u0008/", "\u0008-", "\u0008\\", "\u0008|" };
        Console console = System.console();
        console.printf("|");
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(150);
            console.printf("%s", spinner[i % spinner.length]);
        }
    }
}
```

`\u0008` is the special backspace character. Printing that erases the last character on the line. By starting to print a `|` and then prepending the `\u0008` before all other characters you get the spinner behavior.

Note that this might not be 100% compatible with all consoles (and that [`System.console()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console%28%29) can return `null`).

Also note that you don't necessarily have to use the console class, as printing this sequence to standard output commonly works just as well.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Java natively allows for that. You need to use some external library - maybe [JCurses](http://javacurses.sourceforge.net/) can help you.