# How to show the text of timer in same line in java eclipse

Tags: java, timer, countdowntimer, timertask

I want to show some timer in java eclipse output . I have successfully implement the function but the problem is this that after every second timer is printing in new line but i want to replace the text of each second in same line. For example my i input 12 secs so the output shows like

```
11
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

I want to show the second change in same line. This is my code

```
public class Stopwatch {
static int interval;
static Timer timer;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input seconds => : ");
    String secs = sc.nextLine();
    int delay = 1000;
    int period = 1000;
    timer = new Timer();
    interval = Integer.parseInt(secs);
    System.out.println(secs);
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {
            System.out.println(setInterval());

        }
    }, delay, period);
}

private static final int setInterval() {
    if (interval == 1)
        timer.cancel();
    return --interval;
}
}
```

Comment: use print instead of println .print("") method prints the text on the console and the cursor remains at the end of the text at the console.

Answer (score 1):

You can try printing first the '\r' character as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689323/java-replace-line-of-output-to-standard-out). Also do not use println() but print() method :

```
...
public void run() {
     System.out.print('\r');
     System.out.print(setInterval()); 
}
...
```

Comment: @Sana I tested and it works fine for me. It replaces each value with a new one.

Comment: but not in my case i m using eclipse

Comment: every new second is printing in new linw

Comment: as mentioned use System.out.print and NOT System.out.print*ln*

Answer (score 0):

Console is a LOG-Tool it can't be cleared using code .. you can right click console and choose clear manually .