# How do I set the console cursor position in scala?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to put a simple console spinner into my scala application, but I'm not sure how to set the cursor position?

If it's not possible, is there another way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

```
val chars = List("/", "-", "\\", "|")
(0 to 30).foreach { _ => chars.foreach { cc =>
        print(s"\u0008$cc")
        Thread.sleep(150)
    }
}
```

Idea taken from that answer:
[Write to same location in a console window with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859588/write-to-same-location-in-a-console-window-with-java?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)