# How can i print on the same line in java?

Tags: java

I'm using threads in java to print a counter and increase it every one second. I want the counter to be printed on the previous counter value, but what is actually happening is that the counter is being printed in a new place. How can I do that?

Here is the code and the output in Netbeans:

```
package threads;

public class Threads extends Thread {

    public static int counter = 0;
    
    static synchronized void incrementCounter() {
          System.out.print(counter );
          counter++;
     }

     @Override
     public void run() {
          while(counter<1000){
               incrementCounter();              
              try {
                  sleep(1000);
              } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

              }
          }
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
          Threads te = new Threads();         
          te.start();
     } 
}
```

This is the output:

```
012345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031323334353637383940414243444546474849505152535455565758596061...
```

Comment: Do you want the new printed counter to replace the text of the previous one? So after 5 loops, the console will just show 4 instead of 01234?

Comment: You can use a console library that suports curses-like functionality, or print backspaces over the previous contents manually.

Comment: That is exactly what i want, sorry that the output is not being shown because i'm new in stack overflow     
@coopikoop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write to same location in a console window with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859588/write-to-same-location-in-a-console-window-with-java)

Comment: @AhmedRedwan Don't post expected output in images. Post it as formatted text.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman       done

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by replacing your

```
System.out.print(counter );
```

By

```
System.out.printf("%s", "\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008" + counter );
```

**\u0008** is Backspace.

Comment: You should probably change the number of backspaces according to what's been printed, as otherwise it'll delete other content.